# MVC Foolproof not working for DisplayTextFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

I have a conditional requirement:

```
 [Display(Name = "Contract Number:")]
    [RequiredIf("CandidateType", "Contractor")]
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

```
 @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.CandidateType)

 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.ContractNumber)<br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.ContractNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxForWithTitle(x=>x.ContractNumber, new { @id = "txtContractNumber", @class = "textNormal"})
                </td>
```

But the validation fails because the display for helper does not have the name of the field.  How do you fix this?  It works if I use TextBoxFor and set it to readonly, but it looks silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden input for the value

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CandidateType)
```

or style the element created by `TextBoxFor()` to remove the borders, padding etc. if you want to appear to to look like the element created by `DisplayTextFor()`